# Create a cache object in javascript

Tags: javascript, cache

My intent is to use this object to cache data from web responses. The cache object should only be valid for the current data.

```
var myCache = {

        Cache: { Date: '', Data: [] },

        AddData: function(Name, Data){
            myCache.CheckCache();
            myCache.Cache.Data[Name] = Data;
        },

        GetData: function(Name){
            myCache.CheckCache();
            return myCache.Cache.Data[Name];
        },

        HasData: function(Name){
            myCache.CheckCache();
            var data = myCache.Cache.Data[Name];
            var val = true;
            if(typeof data === "undefined" || data == null || data === '') {
                val = false;
            }
            return val;
        },

        CheckCache: function(){

            var currentDate = myCache.GetCurrentDate();
            var CacheDate = myCache.Cache.Date;
            if(CacheDate != currentDate){
                console.log('Reset Cache');
                myCache.Cache.Data = [];
                myCache.Cache.Date = currentDate;
            }
        },

        GetCurrentDate: function(){
            var today = new Date();
            var dd = today.getDate();
            var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
            var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
            if(dd < 10) {
                dd = '0' + dd;
            } 
            if(mm < 10) {
                mm = '0' + mm;
            } 
            var returnDate = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
            return returnDate;
        }
    };
```

When the main page loads I call

```
myCache.CheckCache();
```

When I get data in the application I use the cache object as

```
   var data;
   if(myCache.HasData('UserData')){
       data = myCache.GetData('UserData');
   } else{
       data = myWebApi.Get(Url);  
   }
```

Is there a better way of creating a cache object? Or any suggestions of improvment

Comment: Your browser already has a cache. Why would you re-implement that? Just use HTTP standards-compliant 304 response codes with Etags.

Comment: Yes, that is true. I want to re-implement it because I would like to se if it can be more efficient than just leaving it to the browser.

Answer (score 2):

> There are two hard things in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors.
>
> Phil Karlton

I'd suggest leaving the job to the browser and to the experts that make it. Additionally, peppering your code with a lot of `if-else` just to use your cache is too much unnecessary effort really.

Now if you insist going in this route...

- First, your function names. They're like from C# land. JavaScript usually uses camel case, with the very first letter in lower case.
- There's no sense storing date in a formatted way. You can store it in milliseconds instead. You can get the current timestamp using `Date.now()`.
- Your cache tracks time globally, not on a per-item basis. This means there will be a period after wiping that you'll be loading stuff fresh instead of the cache.
- An better way to clear an array is to set its `length` property to `0` instead of assigning another array.
- You can take advantage of `localStorage` to cache content more persistently than just in memory. Note that `localStorage` has a size limit of 5-10Mb depending on the browser and it only stores strings (objects need be serialized first).
- Instead of peppering your code with a lot of `if-else` operations, consider making a wrapper function for data-fetching mechanisms. Sort of like a decorator.

  ```
  function cacheWrapper(fn){
    var sourceId = generateIdForFn(fn);
    var isCached = MyCache.hasData(sourceId);
    return isCached ? MyCache.getData(sourceId) : fn();
  }

  function() originalGetter{ return someRemoteApi.getData(); }

  var cachingGetter = cacheWrapper(originalGetter);

  var potentiallyCachedData = cachingGetter();
  ```
- `undefined == null`. It's always best to use strict comparison to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: "An better way to clear an array is to set its length property to 0 instead of assigning another array." - Why is this a better way? One mutates the original array whereas the other lets it go out of scope and get GCed. Hopefully. I think I answered my own question there..

Comment: First of all, Thank u Joseph for the answer. You are very much correct when you say my code look c#ish :) The purpose of using a created cache is just to measure if I can win some time in any way. Mayby I'm in deep water but I got a lot of time to play around just to try:) I really like your wrapper idea, I will do some research on that part.